# Xamarin.iOS Google Maps SDK : ETA annotation for alternate route

Tags: xamarin.ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

Info about App:

- iOS App developed using Xamarin.iOS
- Google Maps SDK used within the app for showing directions and alternate 
  routes from Point A to Point B.

Problem Statement:

- Let's say from Point A to Point B , there are 3 routes shown on the map.
- ETA as an annotation is shown on the MapView by default for one the routes.
- However for the other 2 alternate routes, no ETA information is shown on the map.
- What needs to be done with Google Maps SDK implementation to show ETA for all the routes between Point A & Point B.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios/) does not include the Directions API. So I believe you are using the [web service Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to get the different routes.

### Calculating the ETA:

In order to calculate the ETA for a route you have to iterate through all the **legs** of a route and sum up the **distance.value** attribute.

For more infos about the result set from the Directions API request check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Legs).

### Showing the ETA on the mapView:

On the polyline you drew on the map to represent the route, you may add the [title](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay#a04f4c8cc1cbf24ff6a354820049ca604) attribute with the ETA.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to try this out.